# How to change the android:src in bitmap.xml in code

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

In my android layout I am setting the background image so that it has a faded look (alpha) by referring to another xml like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/contraintLayout1"
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/bg_fade"
```

`bg_fade.xml` then defined like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:alpha="0.3"/>
```

where `background` is my actual jpg image in my `drawables` folder.
This works fine, and I get the faded look I want.

Now I need to change the actual background image depending on the user preference. 
I know I can do this in code for setting a new like this:

```
contraintLayout1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.new_background)
```

But then I no longer have the faded look, just the "raw" image.

So I somehow need to change the src value in the bg_fade.xml file.  But I don't know how I can do this in code.

Can somebody please help?
(PS.  I am coding in Kotlin)

Comment: You cannot modify any app resource at runtime. They're read only and in case of XML resources they just go through a parser that builds whatever object they define.

Comment: @Pawel  Oh, OK.  Not the answer I wanted, but then that is just the way it is!   Thanks for the info, at least I know I have to work around this.

Answer (score 1):

you can first define a method for change transparency of images like this

```
public Bitmap changeTransparency(int src, int value) { 
     Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),src); 
     int width = bMap.getWidth();
     int height = bMap.getHeight();
     Bitmap transBMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
     Canvas canvas = new Canvas(transBMap);
     canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
     final Paint paint = new Paint();
     paint.setAlpha(value);
     canvas.drawBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, paint);    
     return transBMap;
}
```

and then set the returned value to your view's background like this code

```
view.setBackgroundImage(changeTransparency(R.drawable.new_nackground, ALPHA_VALUE));
```

i hope be helpful

Comment: Well setBackgroundImage(...) didn't exist, but I found that creating and returning a resource from the Bitmap meant that I could call setBackground(..).   So this was very helpful so thanks for that.  Although I was hoping for a solution to change the drawable in bg_fade.xml.